# Update existing record or save new record before navigating to other page on button click

Tags: apex, visualforce

When i click on a row from a page block table the details get populated in input text fields page block below the page block table else if i click clear button all input text fields will be cleared and then i will enter new record details in the fields and click on next button. If the record already exists then it should be updated else new record should be saved. Can anyone explain how to do it.

Controller,

```
public with sharing class SearchWizardController {

public list <PCS_Household_Detail__c> phd {get;set;} 
public string searchString {get; set;}
public Id myId {get; set;}
public PCS_Household_Detail__c householdDetails {get; set;}

public SearchWizardController() {
    phd = new List<PCS_Household_Detail__c>();
}

public void search() {
    string searchquery = 'Select Id,Name,Household_Street__c,Household_City__c,Household_State__c,Household_Postal_Code__c,Household_Phone__c,No_of_Children__c,No_of_Existing_Pets__c,Previous_Dog_Owner__c From PCS_Household_Detail__c Where Name Like \'%'+searchString+'%\'';
    phd = Database.query(searchquery);
}

public void clear() {
    phd.clear();
    householdDetails.clear();
}

public PageReference step2() {
    return Page.PetSearchStep2;
}

public PageReference selectRow() {
   string searchquery2 = 'Select Id,Name,Household_Street__c,Household_City__c,Household_State__c,Household_Postal_Code__c,Household_Phone__c,No_of_Children__c,No_of_Existing_Pets__c,Previous_Dog_Owner__c From PCS_Household_Detail__c Where Id = :myId';
   householdDetails = Database.query(searchquery2);    
   return null;
}

}
```

Visualforce,

```
<apex:page controller="SearchWizardController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Household Search Wizard" subtitle="Step 1 of 2"/>
<apex:form >
   <apex:outputPanel id="msg">
         <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages> 
   </apex:outputPanel> 
   <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageblockSection title="Household Detail">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputPanel style="text-align:right" layout="block">
                <apex:outputLabel value="Household :" for="HouseholdName"/>
                <apex:inputText id="HouseholdName" value="{!searchstring}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" rerender="SearchId,msg"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
   </apex:pageblock>

   <apex:pageBlock title="Search Result" id="SearchId">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!phd}" var="a">  
             <apex:column headervalue="Household Name">  
                <apex:actionSupport action="{!selectRow}" event="onclick" rerender="NewHouseholdInfo" >
                    <apex:param name="selectId" value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!myId}" />
                </apex:actionSupport>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}" />     
             </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Household Street" value="{!a.Household_Street__c}"/>  
             <apex:column headerValue="Household City" value="{!a.Household_City__c}"/>  
             <apex:column headerValue="Household State" value="{!a.Household_State__c}"/>  
        </apex:pageblockTable> 
        <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
             <apex:commandButton value="None of These" style="margin-left:92%;" action="{!clear}" reRender="NewHouseholdInfo,SearchId,msg"/>  
        </apex:pageblockButtons>   
   </apex:pageBlock>

   <apex:pageBlock id="NewHouseholdInfo">
        <apex:pageblockSection title="New Household Information" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!householdDetails.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!householdDetails.Household_Street__c}" style="width: 166px"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!householdDetails.Household_City__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!householdDetails.Household_State__c}"/>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
        <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" style="margin-left:25%;" value="Next"/>
        </apex:pageblockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of posting code, I'm going to help you learn for yourself how to do this by giving you a generic description of how to do it, so you can teach yourself. Just giving you the code won't help you learn.

First, the code section in the pageBlock using with title="Result", needs to have an Id assigned to it, not just a title. It gets rendered when a boolean value is true. That way you can use rerender in your command button for that Id. Use that to change the render value of your pageBlock. The boolean will be false by default, so it doesn't get rendered initially.

I hope you're seeing now that you don't need two pages, instead only one. You just use a show/hide and rerender action method to display the results of your query. You can call the rerender portion of your method (again a void method) from your query method to keep if separate if you wish.

That's the general approach to how this is done. Your clear method should also reset the boolean to false and do a rerender at the same time for the lower pageblock (or both).

**Edit**

Below are a few pointers for places in your code for changes that you'll want to make that should point you in the right direction.

```
// As an asside, in your 1st command button, where you have rerender="SearchId,msg"
// "msg" should rerender automatically if there are any page messages    

// in 2nd pageblock below prevents render until query is run. If not, change to 
// check "{!IF(phd, false, true)}" to see if phd is null or has value, below will 
// always work for a true false boolean variable  
<apex:pageBlock id="NewHouseholdInfo" rendered="{!phd}">

// in 2nd pageblock change name of ActionMethod
<apex:actionSupport action="{!ThiSelectRow}" event="onclick" rerender="NewHouseholdInfo" >
<apex:param name="selectId" value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!myId}" />

 // It appears you want below to render when you've selected a specific record in 2nd pageblock, 
// if so, we need to add something to make the render conditional    
<apex:pageBlock id="NewHouseholdInfo" rendered="{!hhInfo}">         

public boolean hhInfo {public get;private set};

// in controller
public PCS_Household_Detail__c householdDetails ThisSelectRow(Id myId) {
   string searchquery2 = 'Select Id,Name,Household_Street__c,Household_City__c,Household_State__c,Household_Postal_Code__c,Household_Phone__c,No_of_Children__c,No_of_Existing_Pets__c,Previous_Dog_Owner__c From PCS_Household_Detail__c Where Id = :myId';
   householdDetails = Database.query(searchquery2);    

   hhInfo = true;

   return this;
}
```

You'll need to add your own save/update record method and a command button to call it.

Once you get this working, I'd recommend you think in terms of changing your methods to create a select list from your initial query that populates your intermediate section. Then, have it autopopulate the first record in the bottom section. You'll then be able to use your "Next" button to move to the next record easily & call the `ThisSelectRow` method.

What you have now isn't going to do that for you. Instead, you'll need to click on each record individually. I don't see an easy way to directly modify it do what you're asking, but someone else might. What I'm seeing is that you'll likely want to generate a select list from your query results and manipulate the selections with your buttons using a method in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I have updated my question. Could you please explain how to do it.